# udev rule for interfacing TIVA launchpad usb-bulk-device without root?

Tags: virtualbox, libusb, udev, texas-instruments

I'm trying to write a program in Linux (Xubuntu) to interface a Tiva launchpad as a usb-bulk device. I use `Code::Blocks` and a `libusb` to write a program at the host side. Everything works ok when I start `Code::Blocks` (or a program) as root. udev rule doesn't work. My udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-TIVA.d` looks like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1CBE", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1CBE", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", MODE="0666"
```

I also added my username to `dialout` and `vboxsf` (I'm running Linux in `Vbox`) groups. Still getting error:

> libusbx couldn't open USB device `/dev/bus/usb/001/006`: Permission denied.
> libusbx requires write access to USB device nodes.